# vcvarsphoneall for Windows Phone with VS2013

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Now that Windows Phone SDK comes with VS2013, where do I locate the vcvarsphoneall for it? It used to be in the VC directory under WPSDK. I presume that using the WinRT version is probably not sufficient. I need this to do a command line compile of a Windows Phone library.

Comment: Looks like it is not included. Any guidance would be much appreciated.